# Why cant deserialize gremlin.process.traversal.Bytecode with none() step?

Tags: deserialization, gremlin, tinkerpop

I try to deserialize traversal query with `none()` step, but it seems like there is no support for such deserialization

Tinkerpop version is `3.5.0`

Here is a code that fail

```
 import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.JavaTranslator;
 import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Bytecode;
 import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Traversal;
 import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal;
 import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource;
 import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Graph;
 import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.GraphReader;
 import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.GraphWriter;
 import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.Mapper;
 import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.*;
 import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph;
 import org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
 
 import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
 import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 
 public class GraphExperimental {
     private static final Mapper<ObjectMapper> GRAPHSON_MAPPER_3_0 = GraphSONMapper.build()
             .version(GraphSONVersion.V3_0)
             .typeInfo(TypeInfo.PARTIAL_TYPES)
             .addCustomModule(GraphSONXModuleV3d0.build().create(false))
             .create();
     private static final GraphWriter GRAPHSON_WRITER_3_0 = GraphSONWriter.build()
             .mapper(GRAPHSON_MAPPER_3_0)
             .create();
     private static final GraphReader GRAPHSON_READER_3_0 = GraphSONReader.build()
             .mapper(GRAPHSON_MAPPER_3_0)
             .create();
 
     private GraphExperimental() {
     }
 
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Graph graph = TinkerGraph.open();
 
         DefaultGraphTraversal<Object, Object> defaultGraphTraversal = new DefaultGraphTraversal<>(graph.traversal());
         // defaultGraphTraversal.addV("A").property("mac", "1");
         defaultGraphTraversal.iterate();
 
         Bytecode bytecode = defaultGraphTraversal.getBytecode();
         String serialize = writeValueAsString(bytecode);
 
         Graph anotherGraph = TinkerGraph.open();
         GraphTraversalSource anotherTraversal = anotherGraph.traversal();
 
         Bytecode bytecodeDeserialized = readValue(serialize, Bytecode.class);
         Traversal.Admin<?, ?> translate = JavaTranslator.of(anotherTraversal).translate(bytecodeDeserialized);
     }
 
     public static <T> T readValue(String value, Class<? extends T> clazz) {
         try (ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(value.getBytes("UTF-8"))) {
             return GRAPHSON_READER_3_0.readObject(in, clazz);
         } catch (IOException e) {
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
         }
     }
 
     public static String writeValueAsString(Object value) {
         try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
             GRAPHSON_WRITER_3_0.writeObject(out, value);
             return out.toString("UTF-8");
         } catch (IOException e) {
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
         }
     }
 }
```

In result i catch such an exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate method: GraphTraversalSource.none()
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.JavaTranslator.invokeMethod(JavaTranslator.java:207)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.JavaTranslator.translate(JavaTranslator.java:89)
    at example.GraphExperimental.main(GraphExperimental.java:63)
```

If you just remove comment from `defaultGraphTraversal.addV("A").property("mac", "1");`

The code will work

So why does there is no support for such a deserialization?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you not attempt to construct a `DefaultGraphTraversal` directly and to instead spawn them from a `GraphTraversalSource` (i.e. your `g`). I suppose it can work, but that class really wasn't designed to be utilized by users directly so the API could shift out from under you or an initialization behavior could change and cause you trouble.

In a sense, the direct construction is what is causing the problem here as you build traversal bytecode that isn't really valid:

```
gremlin> defaultGraphTraversal = new DefaultGraphTraversal<>(graph.traversal());[]
gremlin> defaultGraphTraversal.iterate();[]
gremlin> bytecode = defaultGraphTraversal.getBytecode()
==>[[], [none()]]
```

Since you don't spawn from a `GraphTraversalSource` you end up constructing a traversal that doesn't have any source instructions (i.e. the first `[]` in the above bytecode output). Without that, the `JavaTranslator` heads down a different path than it expects and tries to call `none()` on a `GraphTraversalSource` rather than on a `Traversal`. You obviously solve this problem when you uncomment that line that calls `addV()` because that is a proper start step that can act as a spawn whereas `none()` cannot.

Comment: I heard you, ok, nevertheless

Why dont to throw any exception in `iterate` method, at the time when `iterate` method is used, if no data present, if the design is made about this?

If library allow users to do so, why cant it allow to deserialize the same traversals and then do nothing with deserialized traversal?

I guess, it happends because its usefull, so it would be more usefll, if there will be support for such a serialization

It would be a good feature, i guess

Or there is another reason not to throw such an exception while `iterate`?

Comment: i suppose there could be an exception at traversal iteration if there is no source instruction. offhand, i'm not sure there is a case where that is a valid construction that way.

Comment: Perhaps this use is incorrect, but I stand by my opinion and think that it is convenient. It is better to add a feature than a restriction, especially considering that this does not look like a very difficult improvement.

Comment: i'm not opposing your opinion by any means. i'm just answering your question as to why things are as they are as of this moment. if you feel strongly that something should change, then please feel free to create an issue in JIRA for further discussion in the community: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP and if you have the time then by all means please submit a pull request with a proposed fix. thanks

Comment: and sorry if my last comment led you to believe i was opposing a change. as i re-read what i wrote, it might have come off that way. i was mostly just thinking out loud about whether or not there are valid cases in existing code for construction of bytecode without a source. interestingly even anonymous traversals have a source (i.e. `inject()`) so it may be right to prevent this form of construction.

Comment: I'm sorry, too, if I also offended you in some way, I'm not a big expert in this area, and I didn't even think about the sources of the bytecode, to be honest. Guess, you know better. All the best

Comment: Hi Stephen, do you think, that it is a good solution to use "inject" in case when there is no sources? I mean, as a various of solutions, there can be - to call some methods that produce sources and then call "iterate", so, in that case, what kind of methods you can recommend to use before "iterate"? I think about "math("100/2")" or "inject".
@stephen

Comment: you would have to choose a step that is on `GraphTraversalSource` - http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversalSource.html - `inject()` is one of those so i suppose it would work, but to be honest I don't understand what you're trying to do fully so it's hard to say what's right in this case.

Comment: I can explain. How can i solve such an issue in my code? For example, i can check every GraphTraversal for usage, then i need to add any variable to yank it when GraphTraversal add any data or do any query, then, before "iterate" i need to chekk such a variable and do not iterate if variable is not yanked. Another variant of solution is to make my implementation GraphTraversal and in method iterate check is any sources present, if they not - i want to add some sources and iterate. I guess second solution bettter, cause i dont need to change a lot of outside code usages. Than you for an answer.